# unable to get facebook access token in ios6

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios6, facebook-social-plugins

In iOS6 for posting messages here i am using `ACAccountType and SlRequest` but d=for this i need to retrieve the access token for some operations,

Following is the code which i am using to get data

```
ACAccountType *FBaccountType= [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

            // Specify App ID and permissions
        NSDictionary *dictFB = @{
    ACFacebookAppIdKey:kAppId,
    ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"email",@"publish_stream", @"publish_actions"],
    ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends
        };

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:dictFB completion:
     ^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {
         if (granted) {
             NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:FBaccountType];
//              it will always be the last object with single sign on
             facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
             NSLog(@"facebook account = %@",facebookAccount);

         } else {
                 //Fail gracefully...
             NSLog(@"error getting permission %@",e);
         }
     }];
```

but from the above code i am getting the following data s only 
1]type
2]account description
3]username
4]objectid
5]properties
6]parent account

how can i get the access token using the above code in ios6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the issue has fixed by updated Facebook SDK 3.1.1 library